# Best open source project for learning about high-level domain-level compiler language?

Tags: compiler-construction, dns

I have tried to look for an open source project to learn about language domain level compiler to generate several languages such as Java , .Net platforms.

For example, If I make my own grammars (it can be XML, XSD, or any type of grammar), after compiling it, it produces to java and .NET (c#) language files.

any suggestion I appreciate about it.

Thanks
tiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compiler by definition is program that takes code and produces lower-level code. Did you mean that you are looking for a language-translator, or a de-compiler?

Compiler courses often write a compiler as a project to take in C and produce assembly, usually using Yakk/Bison. To learn about compilers you might consider instead of looking for an open source project, to look for a compiler course with course materials online.

I have not tried any of these but are you looking for something like this:

- http://www.reverberate.org/gazelle/
- http://www.cs.chalmers.se/Cs/Research/Language-technology/BNFC/
- http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing